# Difference between Sharding And Replication on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am just confused about how Sharding and Replication work.

According to the definitions I found in the documentation:

> Replication: A replica set in MongoDB is a group of mongod processes that maintain the same data set.
>
> Sharding: Sharding is a method for storing data across multiple machines.

As per my understanding if I have 75 GB of data then by using replication (3 servers), it will store 75GB data on each server means 75GB on Server-1, 75GB on server-2 and 75GB on server-3. (correct me if I am wrong).

And by using sharding, it will be stored as 25GB data on server-1, 25Gb data on server-2 and 25GB data on server-3. (Right?).

But then I encountered this line in the tutorial:

> Shards store the data. To provide high availability and data
> consistency, in a production sharded cluster, each shard is a replica
> set

As a replica set is 75GB in size, but shard is 25GB in size, then how can they be equivalent?

This makes me quite confused. I think I am missing something obvious. Please help me with this.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11571273/12860895)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

A [**Replica-Set**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-members/) means that you have multiple instances of MongoDB which each mirror all the data of each other. A replica-set consists of one "Primary" and one or more "Secondaries".

All write-operations go to the primary and are then replicated to the secondaries. So writes won't get faster when you add more secondaries.

Read-operations, on the other hand, can be served by any secondary. So when you have a lot of read requests, then you can increase read-performance by adding more secondaries to the replica-set and having your clients distribute their requests to different members of the replica-set.

Replica-sets also offer fault-tolerance. When one of the members of the replica-set goes down, the others take over. When the primary goes down, the secondaries will elect a new primary. For that reason [it is recommended](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-members/) for productive deployment to always use MongoDB as a replica-set of at least three servers, with at least two of them holding data. In that scenario, the third one is a data-less "arbiter" which serves no purpose except electing the remaining secondary as the new primary when the actual primary goes down.

A [**Sharded Cluster**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/) means that each shard of the cluster (which can also be a replica-set) takes care of a part of the data. Each request, both reads and writes, is served by the cluster where the data resides. This means that both read- and write performance can be increased by adding more shards to a cluster. Which document resides on which shard is determined by the *shard key* of each collection. It should be chosen in a way that the data can be evenly distributed on all clusters and so that it is clear for the most common queries where the shard-key resides (example: when you frequently query by `user_name`, your shard-key should include the field `user_name` so each query can be delegated to only the one shard which has that document).

The drawback is that the fault-tolerance suffers. When one shard of the cluster goes down, any data on it is inaccessible. For that reason each member of the cluster should also be a replica-set. This is not required. [When you don't care about high-availability, a shard can also be a single mongod instance without replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-test/). But [for production-use you should always use replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/).

### So what does that mean for your example?

```
                            Sharded Cluster             
             /                    |                    \
      Shard A                  Shard B                  Shard C
        / \                      / \                      / \
+-------+ +---------+    +-------+ +---------+    +-------+ +---------+
|Primary| |Secondary|    |Primary| |Secondary|    |Primary| |Secondary|
|  25GB |=| 25GB    |    | 25 GB |=| 25 GB   |    | 25GB  |=| 25GB    |   
+-------+ +---------+    +-------+ +---------+    +-------+ +---------+
```

When you want to split your data of 75GB into 3 shards of 25GB each, you need at least 6 database servers organized in three replica-sets. Each replica-set consists of two servers who have the same 25GB of data.

You also need servers for the arbiters of the three replica-sets as well as the mongos router and the config server for the cluster. The arbiters are very lightweight and are only needed when a replica-set member goes down, so they can usually share the same hardware with something else. But Mongos router and config-server should be redundant and on their own servers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detail answer...one more question...if the primary is down while a write or read operation is being carried out then..1) what is the delay in selecting the primary from the secondaries and 2) during that delay where will be the data be stored temporarily?

Comment: @SaadSaadi [The primary election process is described in the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/). It takes between 10 and 12 seconds for the secondaries to notice that the primary is down. The primary election itself will usually only take milliseconds. The replica-set is read-only while there is no primary. Any attempts from applications to write data during this time will fail.

Comment: @Philipp: Just two comments: (1) the shard key cannot be modified (i.e. you cannot shard using a different key) and (2) you can read from the secondary nodes of the replica set but consistency depends from the write concern (in order to be consistent the w option should be equal to the replica set sth which is not viable since each shard may have different replica set sizes deliberately or due to node failures).

Comment: @Philipp can you please answer further follow up questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208482/sharding-and-replication-on-mongodb ?

Comment: @Philipp , thank you for the great information! In your last statement, "Mongos router and config-server should be redundant and on their own servers", what is the best practice for making the router/config-server 'redundant'? My naive thinking was that sharding and replicating took care of this.

Comment: @jb This strays away from the original question asked here. Please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 28):

- **Sharding** partitions the data-set into discrete parts.
- **Replication** duplicates the data-set.

These two things can stack since they're different. Using both means you will shard your data-set across multiple groups of replicas. Put another way, you Replicate shards; a data-set with no shards is a single 'shard'.

A Mongo cluster with three shards and 3 replicas would have 9 nodes.

- 3 sets of 3-node replicas.
- Each replica-set holds a single shard.

Comment: For one large file, is it stored into one shard or multiple shard (thus across the nodes)?

Comment: Note that in MongoDB 3.4 or higher, you'll also need mongoDB servers for configuration, and an additional server to act as the mongos router. This brings the total of the 3x3 cluster in your example to 13 servers total.

Answer (score 12):

By **sharding**, you split your collection into several parts.
**Replicating** your database means you make mirrors of your data-set.

Answer (score 7):

In terms of functionality delivered.
Sharding provides scalability and parallelism.
Replication provides availability

Comment: nope, replication only also provides scalability&parallelism given that reads are much more frequent than writes